# file access peek ahead

Tags: python

I need to read a file, line by line and I need to peek into 'the next line' so first I read the file into a list and then I cycle throught the list... somehow this seems rude, building the list could be become expensive.

```
for line in open(filename, 'r'):
    lines.append(line[:-1])

for cn in range(0, len(lines)):
    line = lines[cn]
    nextline = lines[cn+1] # actual code checks for this eof overflow
```

there must be a better way to iterate over the lines but I don't know how to peek ahead

Comment: Why do you need to peek ahead? It's not clear from your code where the "peek ahead" happens, and how you use it.

Comment: I left that peek ahead part out, it was to big and not shedding light on the peek ahead problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for something like the [pairwise](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe from itertools.

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

with open(filename) as f: # Remember to use a with block so the file is safely closed after
    for line, next_line in pairwise(f):
        # do stuff
```

Comment: that's really nice, not easy for me at this time, but if I stand on my toes I can just touch it, thanx!

Comment: oke, getting a better grip on the itertools, however... failing to grasp the exact meaning of next(b, None) ...

Comment: @Paul it advances the iterator b forward one element. If there are no elements left in an iterator then `StopIteration` will be raised. `next` accepts a default argument which it returns if that happens, instead of having the error raised. `None` is just used as a placeholder because if we have reached the end of iteration we won't really be using that value anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way

```
last_line = None

for line in open(filename):                                                                  
    if last_line is not None:
        do_stuff(last_line, line) 
    last_line = line
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `iterator` and do it like this :

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
g = open(filename, 'r')

y = iter(g.readlines())
y.__next__()

for line in f:
    print(line)
    try:
        print(y.__next__())
    except StopIteration:
        f.close()
        g.close()
```

Comment: `g` is already an iterator over the lines of the file so there is no need for `y`. Also I presume you are using python 3 since you called `__next__`, you should just use `next(y)` if you actually needed to. I don't think it's a good idea to open the same file twice anyway, my solution uses `tee` to do this. You should also `close` the files or use a `with` block.

Comment: `next(y)` doesnt work in python 3. And g is a `TextIOWrapper` object. So, even if it is an iterable object it doesnt have `next()` method to. And yeah, it probably isnt a good idea to open same file twice, but its only in read mode, so dont think it does much harm.

Comment: Yeah, using `tee` is probably a better approach, but tried to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: `next` does work in python 3. `__next__` was created for that very reason. It is supposed to be hidden for `next` only to use, hence the preceeding and trailing `__`